# deleting object that was initialized by dereferencing new object

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I've got the following class:

now I've been thinking of implementing my constructor this way:

basically dereferncing the object returned by the new operation.
now ... this feels wrong and I should probably should have be working with pointers, but I'd like to challange myself to maybe get this to work and learn something new.

So my problem will be deleting this object... my destructor for Dense does not work as I have it like this:

but obviously I'm getting this error:

free(): invalid pointer

so how can I go about freeing the allocated memory with the way I have this implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.   The initialisers in the constuctor have gone out of their way to lose track of the objects created with `new`, after using them to initialise another object.   The destructor has undefined behaviour since `&weights` etc were not allocated with operator `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so how can I go about freeing the allocated memory with the way I have this implemented?

You simply can't and you have created a memory leak.

---

**Explanation:**

When you write:

```
int a = *(new int(5)); // Really bad
```

You basically:

- allocate an `int` on the heap
- dereference the r-value
- assign it (copy) to a variable on the stack

At no moment you did care to keep the returned pointer of the `new` statement. `a` is **another** `int` that is a **copy** of what you've allocated on the heap.

You can't delete `a` because it is created on the stack. As `a` is another object, the address of `a` **is not the same** as the address of the `int` you've allocated on the heap with `new`.

So deleting `&a` is obviously <s>forbidden</s> Undefined Behaviour and cannot in any way delete the `int` that you've created with `new`. And as you did not stored the returned pointer of the `new` statement, you have no way to retrieve it: This is a memory leak.

---

If you got a reference instead of a copy, you would be able to delete it:

```
int & a = *(new int(5));
delete &a; // fine
```

But it is an over-complicated, less efficient and pointless way of simply doing:

```
int a = 5; // destroyed at scope's end
```

Comment: "deleting `&a` is obviously forbidden".   Nup.    The behaviour is undefined but there is no rule that forbids anyone from doing that.      (Whether it is a good thing to do, is another question entirely).

Comment: @Peter You're right. For me, Undefined Behaviour is forbidden, but it's only a personal rule. I'll correct it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do it this complicated. You can call the constructors directly from the initializer list. There is absolutely no need for `new` here. Also you don't need to `delete` those objects. Their destructors will be called automatically if `Dense` gets destroyed.

```
Dense::Dense(): weights(), //Calls constructor Matrix()
                bias(), //Calls constructor Matrix()
                act(ActivationType::Relu), //Calls constructor Activation(ActivationType::Relu)
                input() //Calls constructor Matrix()
{}
```

---

Also, what you are trying to do with pointers wont work. For example `&bias` will be the address of the member variable bias and has nothing to do with the pointer returned by `new Matrix()`.

Comment: Yeah that pretty sums up my question, if I were going to do this stupid way of code, how could I delete the pointer that was returned by new Matrix()?
Is there even a way to do that with only having the copy I have in bias?

Comment: No, you would have to store the actual `Matrix*` returned by `new Matrix()`.